# How to install packages using source package on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

When I try to install a software using apt-get, it told me
*`packages have unmet dependencies`*, so I want to install the dependencies manual, but when I found the dependencies in website:**packages.ubuntu.com**, it has three file:
**xxx.dsc**  **xxx.orig.tar.xz  xxx.debian.tar.xz**

I'm wondering how to install the package using these three file on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are are mixing different things. Debian packages installable with `apt-get` are binary packages. When apt-get says that there are unmet deps, it is most likely means that it can not find the binary dependencies of specific versions. The solution should be to run `apt-get update` to update the list of packages to the latest state. However if you need to build a source package, you could consider looking into `dget` and `debuild` tools from `devscripts` debian package and even better look into debian packaging manual.

Comment: thats not completely true what your telling, maybe u missed the option `apt build-dep` option which is to fetch all deps that be needed to build the source package ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your question indicates that are mixing some things. Most likely something is wrong with your software repository list, see [Ubuntu community help: repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).

However, to answer your question:

To install source packages in Ubuntu, the correct command is `apt-src`.

First step (after installation of apt-src) is to make sure you have the appropriate deb-src lines in your sources.list.

To download the sources and to build `<package>`, then to install the resulting package, the commands are:

```
sudo apt-src update
sudo apt-src --build install <package>
sudo dpkg --install <path to compiled .deb>
```

More can be found in [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/apt-src) - see there.